# How to get simple array in sequelize findAll()?

Tags: javascript, async-await, sequelize.js

I'm trying to get all rows with specific ID in `async/await` style using `sequelize`. My code looks like:

**UPDATED:**

```
router.get('/', errorHandler(async (req, res, next) => {

    let domainsDB = await Domain.findAll({
            where: { accID: accID },
            attributes: [`adID`, `domain`, `status`]
    })

}
```

When I `console.log(domainsDB)` I see this:

```
[ 
     domains {
       dataValues: [Object],
       _previousDataValues: [Object],
       _changed: {},
       _modelOptions: [Object],
       _options: [Object],
       __eagerlyLoadedAssociations: [],
       isNewRecord: false },
     domains {
...
...
...
]
```

The [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#-findall-search-for-multiple-elements-in-the-database) says it has to be an array in return. But console log shows this is an object. The data in this object in `dataValues` is correct. There are my domains. But I expect to get an array to work with.

How to get an array in return with `async/await?` Thank you for any help.

Comment: Where do you console.log ? is it immediate call after ``let domainsDB``?

Comment: @MehiShokri Yes, it's

Comment: It's because you're getting the created json object. not the answer.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting an array? Your return result starts with `[` and ends with `]`

Comment: @KhauriMcClain Yes, it's an array. I expected more convenient array I think. But now I see promise returns the same array as async/await. Probably it's the expected behavior of sequelize

Comment: According to the [reference](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll) it returns an array of [Models](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#instance-method-get), not plain objects. And that's what you have. NodeJS or whatever console you're using is unpacking the `Model's` methods and fields, so maybe it's sort of deceptive looking. I believe the question has been answered already, but I'd say in general the models themselve have a lot of useful features to consider as well.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

All you need is : `raw : true` ,

```
let domainsDB = await Domain.findAll({
    where: { accID: accID },
    attributes: [`adID`, `domain`, `status`],
    raw : true // <--- HERE
})
```

By default model queries returns the `sequelize` Object , to get the plain result we need to pass `raw : true`

Comment: @Nastro , Glad to know :) , Happy Coding BTW.

Comment: why it will return non array when including hasmany assosiation?

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur you may have had to use a "nested: true" in the options for a non-flat object

Comment: raw is not a good option if you use association.

Answer (score -1):

await should be wrapped in a function with async key in it.

A correct code snippet would look like this:

```
async fetchData(accID) {
  return await Domain.findAll({
      where: { accID: accID },
      attributes: [`adID`, `domain`, `status`]
  })
}

let data = fetchData(1);
console.log(data);
```

Alternative approaches are: 1) using generator functions 2) promises.

They're basically the same thing in a manner that it makes your synchronous code act as asynchronous.

Comment: But I wrapped it already in `router.get()` method. See my updated code in question.

Comment: Alright, you were getting it inside the async function.(Didn't mention it though). probably your solution is passing ``raw:true`` option.