# Sequelize js reformat nested response

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using PostgreSQL as database and Sequelize JS to Query my database. One of the APIs has below code

```
var video_attributes = [[sequelize.cast(sequelize.fn("like_count", Sequelize.col("video_id")), 'integer'), "total_likes"]];
  if (request.user) {
    video_attributes.push([sequelize.fn("has_liked", request.user.id, Sequelize.col("user_bookmark.video_id")), "is_liked"]);
    video_attributes.push([sequelize.fn("has_bookmarked", request.user.id, Sequelize.col("user_bookmark.video_id")), "is_bookmarked"]);
  }

  mod_idx.user_bookmark.findAll({
    where: {"user_id": request.user.id},
    include : [{
      model:mod_idx.video, as: "video",
      attributes: {include: video_attributes}
    }],
    attributes: {exclude: ["user_id", "video_id", "id"]},
    order: [[
        "id",
        "desc"
      ]],
  }).then(video_list => {
    let r = { "data": video_list, "success": true }
    response.status(200).json(r)
  }).catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err)
  });
```

It returns below response:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "video": {
                "id": 189,
                "total_likes": 0,
                "is_liked": false,
                "is_bookmarked": true
            }
        },
        {
            "video": {
                "id": 261,
                "total_likes": 0,
                "is_liked": false,
                "is_bookmarked": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "success": true
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 189,
            "total_likes": 0,
            "is_liked": false,
            "is_bookmarked": true
        },
        {
            "id": 261,
            "total_likes": 0,
            "is_liked": false,
            "is_bookmarked": true
        }
    ],
    "success": true
}
```

- I tried by making "raw" as true but it returns column names as 'video.column_name' (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53612698/1030951).
- I don't want to use map function as it may slowdown while processing large number of records.

Answer (score 0):

It is not pretty but you can do this by adding all attributes at top level.

```js
mod_idx.user_bookmark.findAll({
  where: {"user_id": request.user.id},
  include : [{
    model:mod_idx.video, as: "video",
    attributes: []  // Do not include anything in nested object
  }],
  attributes: [
    [sequelize.cast(sequelize.fn("like_count", Sequelize.col("video.video_id")), 'integer'), "total_likes"] 
    // Add more here 
  ],
  order: [[
    "id",
    "desc"
  ]],
})
```

================================================================

**Update**

You can do something like this. One thing to consider here is that you must avoid the column name conflicts across multiple tables (as you are putting all attributes at top level), so add exclude or rename to make sure you handle the conflicts.

I demonstrate here for a scenario that I want to include all video attributes except certain columns to avoid conflicts.

```js
const videoExcludeList = ['createdAt', 'updatedAt'];

// Get all video attributes minus exclude list.
const videoAttrs = Object.keys(mod_idx.video.rawAttributes)
    .filter((v) => !videoExcludeList.includes(v))
    .map((v) => Sequelize.col(`video.${v}`));

// Custom attributes that uses fn/rename/etc
const customAttrs = [
    [sequelize.cast(sequelize.fn("like_count", Sequelize.col("video.video_id")), 'integer'), "total_likes"],
    // Add more here.
]
```

You can also combine with top-level exclude to exclude columns from `user_bookmark`.

```js
mod_idx.user_bookmark.findAll({
  where: {"user_id": request.user.id},
  include : [{
    model:mod_idx.video, as: "video",
    attributes: []  // Do not include anything in nested object
  }],
  attributes: {
    exclude: ['id'], // exclude these columns from user_bookmark
    include: [...videoAttrs, ...customAttrs],
  },
  order: [[
    "id",
    "desc"
  ]],
  raw: true  // You need this.
})
```

Comment: My table has many columns, will need to rename all. Is there any better approach than this ?

Comment: Which table has many columns?  And is it many and not all?

Comment: Video table has 20 columns, I haven't mentioned all due to privacy reasons.

Comment: I updated my answer, please check.  Having just a `Sequelize.col('video.x')` at top level will resolve the name to just `x` in response but if you want to have it other than `x`, you can change `map` function as you like.